# Lambda Recursion in Dr Racket

Tags: recursion, lambda, lisp, syntax-error, racket

Im trying to created the function "apply N times" in Dr Racket but Don't know where I'm going wrong. My code seems to be correct but clearly I'm missing something. Printed below is the code and the error I'm getting.

```
(define (applyNtimes F n)
  (lambda (x)
    (if (= n 0) x 
        (F (applyNtimes F (- n 1))))))

(define cdr3 (applyNtimes cdr 3))

(cdr3 '(1 2 3 4 4 5))
```

and This is the error I'm getting:

```
cdr: contract violation
  expected: pair?
  given: #
```

the expected output should be

```
(4 4 5)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the problem, you are trying to apply `F` to the return of `applyNtimes` but think for a second, what does that return? **a lambda**.

This means in your case, we're trying to apply `cdr` to a lambda, whoops.

In order to get the value of this lambda to actually use it, we have to invoke it. Doing this is pretty easy, just changing

```
(F (applyNtimes F (- n 1))))))
```

to

```
(F ( (applyNtimes F (- n 1)) ;;Get the Lambda
     x))))) ;; and apply it to x
```

To understand this let's break it apart, first we apply `F` to something. Since in our case `F` is really `cdr` we'd better give it some form of pair.

In this code the 'Something' is the result of applying `(applyNTimes F (- n 1))` to `x`.

Well this leads us to some recursion, where what we're really doing is

```
(F (F (F ... ((applyNTimes F (- n whatever)) x))))
```

Ok so how does this recursion end? Well when `(- n whatever)` is 0, we return the lambda

```
(lambda (x) x)
```

Which really turns this whole thing into

(F (F (F (F (F (F x))))))

Which is our desired applyNtimes function.

Comment: This works but can you explain the syntax? my brain gets fried somewhere between the parentheses. correct me if I'm wrong but is this what your doing?

    (cdr ( (lambda) x))

Comment: @TdotThomas Edited with a more complete explanation